# How to call the average difference between successive values

Tags: discrete-mathematics, means

In statistics when you have dataset of values say: $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\},$ the mean of differences between every two consecutive observations is $1$. For the dataset $\{1,2,6\}$, it is $2.5$. 
For $\{1,2,3\}$ it is $1$. For $\{1,2,4\},$ it is $1.5$.

Is there a name for this? Some people suggest "moving average," but I'm not sure.

Comment: the mean of the sequences of differences ?

Comment: Not here to question your work, but did you notice that the mean between $a_{n+1}-a_n$ and $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}$ is just $\dfrac{a_{n+2}-a_n}{2}$ ? (i.e. the fact that there is a number in between does not matter at all)

Comment: What would be the 'mean difference' values for datasets $\{1,1,7\}$ and $\{1,7,1\}$...?

Comment: @CiaPan: Aha! You have noticed the importance of sorting the observations in ascending order. See my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a special name for this. But @RoddyMcPhee has suggested
something reasonable. (And I have another suggestion later.)

You may be
interested to know that there are related functions in R statistical
software. The function `diff` finds the differences between adjacent
observations. The function `mean` finds the sample mean.

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
d.x = diff(x); d.x
## 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
mean(d.x)
## 1
```

Notice that this method makes sense only if the values are *sorted* in increasing
order.

Using the Comment by @G.Sassatelli, sorting is not necessary, but we do need
to know the maximum and the minimum.

```
(max(x) - min(x))/(length(x)-1)
## 1
```

Here is a simulation of an application of your idea. We put 1000 observations
at random into the interval $(0,1).$ Then sort them, and view the result as
sequential arrival times of a process. The 'interarrival times' (times
between successive arrivals) are very nearly distributed according to
an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda = 1/1000.$ Accordingly,
the mean of the interarrival times should be about $\mu = 1/\lambda = 0.001.$

```
y = runif(1000)        # generate 1000 obs from UNIF(0,1)
d.y = diff(sort(y))    # 999 interarrival times
mean(d.y)
## 0.0009988142        # aprx mean interarrival time, exact = 0.001
```

Here is a histogram of the inter-arrival times along with the 
density function of the exponential distribution with rate 1/1000.

[image]

Therefore, in a situation like this where the sorted data values are
viewed as interarrival times of a process, the terminology
you may be looking for is **mean interarrival time**.

*Note:* I have to admit a small discrepancy in this example. Because
the simulation *forced* there to be *exactly* 1000 arrivals in one unit
of time, the (conditional) distribution of interarrival times is not *exactly* exponential. 
(However, a Kolmogorv-Smirnov goodness-of-fit test fails to detect the
discrepancy, $\text{P-value }\approx 0.8.$)